# Yii import autorize.net vendor

Tags: yii, autoload, authorize.net

I am new in Yii.
I have project where already implemented payment system (autorize.net)

Here is what I have.

In config file

```
return CMap::mergeArray(

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/main.php'),
array(
    'import'=>array(
    'application.vendor.authorize.*',
            'application.vendor.authorize.lib.*',
            'application.vendor.authorize.lib.shared.*',
```

And after this I can use this like this

```
$details  = new AuthorizeNetTD;
```

Now I need to use [this](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/CustomerProfiles/get-customer-payment-profile.php) functional.
I am trying to call all needed files like this

```
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.NameAndAddressType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.CreditCardSimpleType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.CreditCardType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.CustomerAddressType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.CustomerDataType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.CustomerType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.DriversLicenseType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.OrderType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.MerchantAuthenticationType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.PaymentType", true);
Yii::import("application.vendor.authorize.lib.net.authorize.api.contract.v1.TransactionRequestType", true);
```

The directory structure looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/fa2fe9b08bc395ecb159df46696f741d):

But it doesn't work. I have errors like this

```
array(7) {
  ["code"]=>
  int(500)
  ["type"]=>
  string(11) "PHP warning"
  ["message"]=>
  string(89) "include(MerchantAuthenticationType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
  ["file"]=>
  string(57) "D:\xampp\htdocs\satellitedirect\yii\framework\YiiBase.php"
  ["line"]=>
```

How can I use Autorize.net  SDK autoloader in Yii that I will not need to call files separatly.

Comment: Try this http://shishirsingh.name/2015/09/17/how-to-use-third-party-autoloaders-in-yii/

Comment: I used this when was implementing google API and it works.
I tried call authorie.net autoloader similar way but it doesn't work. 
But I can't figuring out what I am doing wrong here.